# DNS root hints at 2012 R2

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012

What is the recomended site to fullfill all DNS root hints box in windows server 2012 R2? I see a 'copy from server' button below the box, but I have no idea what site can we use to import DNS root hints.
Second question; after we fullfill the DNS root hints, should we write forwarders too?
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can get the root hints file from the [IANA site](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/files) or specifically [named.root](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/files)

Answer (score 2):

This is what my root.hint file says about it:

```
;       This file holds the information on root name servers needed to
;       initialize cache of Internet domain name servers
;       (e.g. reference this file in the "cache  .  <file>"
;       configuration file of BIND domain name servers).
;
;       This file is made available by InterNIC
;       under anonymous FTP as
;           file                /domain/named.cache
;           on server           FTP.INTERNIC.NET
;       -OR-                    RS.INTERNIC.NET
;
;       last update:    Jan 3, 2013
;       related version of root zone:   2013010300
;
; formerly NS.INTERNIC.NET
```

I know it is taken from BIND, but the Root DNS are the same. So, download a copy from there and then upload it to your server (in case the download buttons downloads the file from elsewhere).